# what this mean after the eldest daughter?

Tags: grammar

Today i found the word "MySQL is named after the eldest daughter of Ulf Michael Widenius"

I don't clear the meaning of this statement.

After the eldest daughter is 
1.second daughter name is MySQL?
2.give this name after born the first daughter?

Can you explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the statements means Mr. Michael Widenius have a daughter, her name is 'My', based on which he named the query language 'MySQL'.

Hope this helps.

*Obviously I had to google her name*

Comment: Just realized that you are trouble by the phrase 'named after'.
named after doesn't mean that the language was based on Michael's daughter who was born 'after' My.

'named after' is a phrasal verb

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/name-after